# GeoIP installed / loaded, but not returning records

Tags: php, geolocation, geoip, php-extension

Attempting to geolocate country and region via GeoIP Module / MaxMind DB.

Double checked it's loaded via phpinfo():

```
 geoip
 geoip support  enabled
 geoip extension version    1.0.8
 geoip library version  1004005
```

Double checked the DB:

```
    <?
    $db = geoip_database_info();
    print_r($db);
    ?>
```

Returns:

```
GEO-106FREE 20090201 Build 1 Copyright (c) 2007 MaxMind LLC All Rights Reserved
```

But when I try this:

```
<?
$record = geoip_record_by_name("76.109.14.196");
if ($record) {
   print_r($record);
}
?>
```

It turns up blank.

Is there a piece I'm missing?

Comment: Returns the associative array on success, or FALSE if the address *cannot be found in the database.* Have you tried other IPs?

Comment: Try this: `$details = geoip_record_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $details['city'];`

Comment: @hookman yes, have tried other IPs.

Answer (score 0):

The Database might be outdated. Why don't use use a remote solution that is properly updated such as http://www.geoplugin.net/

Simple Example

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=76.109.14.196");
echo $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;
```

Output

```
 United States
```

Comment: Should be mentioned that remote solution is slower and may be down.

Comment: You can combine it with cache solution like `memcache` how many request are you look at per min ?

Comment: This is an acceptable alternative, but I'm interested in solving the original problem (for the sake of understanding, and also for the reasons @hookman listed).

Answer (score 0):

The specific database for location lookups is probably not installed. Try `geoip_country_code_by_name` and it should work.